# Exception while stopping repeating

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, camera, storing-data

Even after closing the camera intent, I'm getting this error message.
I'm trying to save the image file after it is captured by the camera. I've created the file path, so the image can be saved by the uri. But when the camera is closing, it gives me this error.

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS){
            if(allPermissionGranted()){
                startCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted by the user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
```

The error message is this:

```
020-11-23 16:23:24.248 5649-8228/com.example.camera E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_DISCONNECTED (2): cancelRequest:518: Camera device no longer alive
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1149)
```

Any help will be appreciated.